# Is it necessary to include "Connection: Keep-Alive" in the response message?

Tags: networking, http

Based on my understanding, a server uses the `Connection: Keep-Alive` header in the response message to tell the client that it will not close the connection after sending the response message.

But is it necessary for the server to include this header in the response message? or is it the default behavior for the server not to close the connection after sending the response message, and if the server wants to close the connection, then it would use the `Connection: close` header?

I am talking about HTTP/1.1.

Comment: Different web servers might have different defaults.  Which one are you using?  Feel free to edit that fact into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fast answer no "No". Keep-Alive headers are HTTP 1.0 syntax and are not included i the HTTP 1.1 definition.  HTTP 1.1 defaults to persistent connections, and does not need a mechanism to request them.

Please refer to the RFCs for questions like this.  HTTP 1.1 us defined in RFCs [7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) thru [7237](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7237).  The RFCs are available in a number of formats.

From the old HTTP1.1 specification  [RFC2068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-19.7.1.1)

> 19.7.1.1 The Keep-Alive Header

> When the Keep-Alive connection-token has been transmitted with a
> request or a response, a Keep-Alive header field MAY also be
> included. The Keep-Alive header field takes the following form:

> ```
>      Keep-Alive-header = "Keep-Alive" ":" 0# keepalive-param
> ```

> ```
>      keepalive-param = param-name "=" value
> ```

> The Keep-Alive header itself is optional, and is used only if a
> parameter is being sent. HTTP/1.1 does not define any parameters.

> If the Keep-Alive header is sent, the corresponding connection token
> MUST be transmitted. The Keep-Alive header MUST be ignored if
> received without the connection token.